# Postgres jsonb query array of objects

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

[image]

I am trying to a do a query to Postgres 15 to return the room id, querying by 2 userid.

Example: I want to get the roomid, querying by the userid:1 and userid:2 then get his userid, I don't realize how to do it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM room 
WHERE users @> '[{"userid":"1"},{"userid":"2"}]'::jsonb
```

Comment: What is the data in the table? What is the schema of the table? What exactly is the desired result? Please [do not post a link to a painting of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret the image correctly, the array in the first row contains `{"userid": 2}` and not `{"userid": "2"}`. There is a difference between the number `2` and the string `"2"` in JSON.